# bound field round off the decimal values

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a bound filed in gridveiw and I need only two letter after decimal, but third letter is round off in second

> Value: 2.777
>
> Output: 2.78
>
> Desired output: 2.77

I am using code below

```
<asp:BoundField datafield="SCPA" 
                headertext="SCPA" 
                HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                DataFormatString="{0:N2}">
</asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to create a function in codebehind:

```
protected object TruncateNumber(object num)
{
     double dnum = Double.Parse(num.ToString());
     dnum = ( (double) ( (int) (dnum * 100.0) ) ) / 100.0 ;
     return dnum;
}
```

On your aspx side:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#TruncateNumber(Eval("Number")) %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: DataFormatString="{0:.##}" its also roundoff the value

Comment: how can we store in 'which data type' only two num after decimal and not roundoff the num in sql